# maven project in VScode- imports cannot be resolved

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code

I got a very simple netbeans projectthat I want to use in VSCode.

I followed the details and installed the relevant extensions, mavan etc.

After I created the maven project, pom.xml and all, I added the sources, and left out with some 3rd party jar files referenced in the source code, that were originally under /lib folder on the previous project.

Those jars are not in maven repo' and don't have a pom.xml.

I would like to know what is the correct way to reference those jar files, especially because they don't have a version- I tried mvn install.. and the folder hierarchy is not the same as it was (should it change? somelib.jar becoming somelib-1.0.jar?)

Should I create another local repo'?

Can I leave them where they are and just reference them somehow?

What should be done to remove the "problems" VScode points out, and have the editor/linter understand the import statements? (the import statements were not resolved after using mvn install to add the package to the .m2 repo)
Thanks for any help!

All the best,